# Consolidate PHP Array on special Key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

What is the best pratice to consolidate arrays on a special key?

```
Pseudocode:
If A[i]["name"]==A[j]["name"] and i!=j
then 
{
A[i]["desc"]+=A[j]["desc"] 
array_slice(A,j,1)
}
```

and

```
My Approach:
for ($i=0;$i<count($set);$i++)

{

    for($j=0;$j<count($set);$j++)

    {


        if (($i!=$j) and

            (strcmp($set[$i]["name"],$set[$j]["name"]) == 0))
        {
            $set[$i]["name"].=",".$set[$j]["name"];
            array_slice($set,$j,1)
        }
    }
}
```

This isnt work like excepted i my current Project. Same Implemantation works great on a other Project. 
But i think there are a smarter way to do this.

```
What it should do:
Before Operation:
A[0]["name"]="Test";
A[0]["desc"]="3,5";

A[1]["name"]="Test";
A[1]["desc"]="8,9";

A[2]["name"]="OtherTest";
A[2]["desc"]="4,3";

After Operation:

A[0]["name"]="Test";
A[0]["desc"]="3,5,8,9";

A[1]["name"]="OtherTest";
A[1]["desc"]="4,3";
```

Comment: Can you show a part of the array `$set` please

Comment: Hmm. Maybe an array_intersect type function to whittle down what you are comparing? Honestly nothing really suggests itself to me. Would likely end up with a solution using similar looping.

Comment: I can see what you are attempting to do. The problem is `array_slice` doesn't actually remove anything from the array. It just extracts and **returns** a portion of it. You probably wanted to do `unset($set[$j])`. That will remove the element at `$j`. Also, it looks like you are concatenating `name`, but didn't you want to append `desc` to each other?

Comment: $set looks like the pseudocode above.

Comment: yes unset() is the function i needed

Comment: and also yes i want to concat desc, just a mistake by typing this thread

Answer (score 1):

The easier logic might be to index the result on `name`:

```
foreach($A as $values) {
    $desc[$values['name']][] = $values['desc'];
    $result[$values['name']] = $values;
}
```

Then you can map and implode the `desc`:

```
$result = array_map(function($v) use($desc) {
                        $v['desc'] = implode(',', $desc[$v['name']]);
                        return $v;
                    }, $result);
```

This yields:

```
Array
(
    [Test] => Array
        (
            [name] => Test
            [desc] => 3,5,8,9
        )
    [OtherTest] => Array
        (
            [name] => OtherTest
            [desc] => 4,3
        )
)
```

To get numeric indexes instead of the `name` just re-index:

```
$result = array_values($result);
```

Comment: this is not working for me since i have other fields additional to "names" on the array which have to be the same for consolidate the desc

Comment: That would have been pertinent info to put in the question wouldn't it?

Comment: Edited to include all keys.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach:

```
$a = [
    ['name' => 'Test', 'desc' => '3,5'],
    ['name' => 'Test', 'desc' => '8,9'],
    ['name' => 'OtherTest', 'desc' => '4,3']
];

$b = [];

$a = array_filter($a, function ($elm) use (&$b) {
    if (isset($b[$elm['name']])) {
        $b[$elm['name']] .= ',' . $elm['desc'];
        return false;
    } else {
        $b[$elm['name']] = '';
        return true;
    }
});

$a = array_map(function ($elm) use ($b) {
    return ['name' => $elm['name'], 'desc' => $elm['desc'] . $b[$elm['name']]];
}, $a);

$a = array_values($a);

var_dump($a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for advices. I found a Solution to my Problem with help of using a combination of unset() and array_vlaues()

EDIT: this seems to be very unefficient like my this script breaks the´phps standard maximun execution time of 30s on just medium length arrays

```
$set[0]["name"]="Test";
$set[0]["desc"]="3,4";
$set[1]["name"]="Test";
$set[1]["desc"]="7,8";
$set[2]["name"]="OtherTest";
$set[2]["desc"]="1,2";

for ($i=0;$i<count($set)-1;$i++)
{
    for($j=0;$j<count($set) ;$j++)
    {
        if (($i!=$j) and (strcmp($set[$i]["name"],$set[$j]["name"]) == 0)) 
        {   
            $set[$i]["desc"].=",".$set[$j]["desc"]; //concat desc
            unset($set[$j]); // remove item at index 0
            $set = array_values($set); // reindex array
        }
    }
}
```